# Why when I set a low duration value for my CABasicAnimation does it jump?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, cabasicanimation

**Sample Project:** http://cl.ly/1W3V3b0D2001

I'm using `CABasicAnimation` to create a progress indicator that is like a pie chart. Similar to the iOS 7 app download animation:

[image]

The animation is set up as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2;
    CGFloat inset  = 1;
    CAShapeLayer *ring = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    ring.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)
                                           cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;

    ring.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    ring.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    ring.lineWidth = 2;

    self.innerPie = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    inset = radius/2;
    self.innerPie.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)
                                               cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;
    self.innerPie.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    self.innerPie.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.innerPie.lineWidth = (radius-inset)*2;

    self.innerPie.strokeStart = 0;
    self.innerPie.strokeEnd = 0;

    [self.layer addSublayer:ring];
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.innerPie];

    self.progress = 0.0;
}
```

The animation is triggered by setting the progress of the view:

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.progress = progress;

    if (animated) {
        CGFloat totalDurationForFullCircleAnimation = 0.25;

        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
        pathAnimation.delegate = self;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = @([self.innerPie.presentationLayer strokeEnd]);
        pathAnimation.toValue = @(progress);
        pathAnimation.duration = totalDurationForFullCircleAnimation * ([pathAnimation.toValue floatValue] - [pathAnimation.fromValue floatValue]);

        [self.innerPie addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
    }
    else {
        [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
        [CATransaction begin];
        self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}
```

However, in cases where I set the progress to something small, such as `0.25`, there's a jump in the animation. It goes a little forward clockwise, jumps back, then keeps going forward as normal. It's worth nothing that *this does not happen if the duration or progress is set higher*.

How do I stop the jump? This code works well in every case except when the progress is very low. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't configure the transaction outside of `begin` and `commit`. You could end up affecting something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah! We should have seen this earlier. The problem is this line in your `if (animated)` block:

```
self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
```

Since innerPie is a Core Animation layer, this causes an implicit animation (most property changes do). This animation is fighting with your own animation. You can prevent this from happening by disabling implicit animation while setting the strokeEnd:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
[CATransaction commit];
```

(Note how `setDisableActions:` is within the begin/commit.)

Alternatively, you can remove your own animation and just use the automatic one, using something like `setAnimationDuration:` to change its length.

Original Suggestions:

My guess is that your `drawRect:` is being called, which resets your strokeEnd value. Those layers should probably not be set up in `drawRect:` anyway. Try moving that setup to an init method or `didMoveToWindow:` or similar.

If that's not effective, I would suggest adding log statements to track the value of `progress` and `[self.innerPie.presentationLayer strokeEnd]` each time the method is called; perhaps they're not doing what you expect.

Comment: Hmm, I moved it out of `drawRect`, and started logging when `setProgress:animated:` is called, but neither helped. The logging only shows 0.0 for the strokeEnd and progress when it's called the first time to set it to 0.1, which is the only time it's called. Here's a sample project: http://cl.ly/1W3V3b0D2001

Comment: @DougSmith Based on your sample project, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Here is the link to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW3) that proves the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using drawRect:? There should be no `drawRect:` method in your class.

You should not be using drawRect if you are also using self.layer. Use one or the other, never both.

Change it to something like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    return nil;

  CGFloat radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2;
  CGFloat inset  = 1;
  CAShapeLayer *ring = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  ring.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)
                                        cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;

  ring.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  ring.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  ring.lineWidth = 2;

  self.innerPie = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  inset = radius/2;
  self.innerPie.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, inset, inset)
                                            cornerRadius:radius-inset].CGPath;
  self.innerPie.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  self.innerPie.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  self.innerPie.lineWidth = (radius-inset)*2;

  self.innerPie.strokeStart = 0;
  self.innerPie.strokeEnd = 0;

  [self.layer addSublayer:ring];
  [self.layer addSublayer:self.innerPie];

  self.progress = 0.0;

  return self;
}
```

Comment: I moved it out of `drawRect`, though nothing changed. Here's a sample project: http://cl.ly/1W3V3b0D2001

Comment: Moving it to initWithFrame is the right thing to do, but it hasn't solved the problem. Sorry I've never worked with `CAShapeLayer` before, however I had a look at your code and after making this change: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147461/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-23%20at%2012.59.21%20pm.png it works perfectly (with animated:YES). I'm not sure how you would make it work with animated:NO, and there's no obvious way to control the animation speed. I'd have to research CAShapeLayer further.

Comment: Basically it appears CAShapeLayer does all the animation stuff for you, and it falls to shit if you try to add your own animation on top. Presumably there is some way to do the animation properly, I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

When travelling within same distance, the smaller the duration, the higher the speed. When you set the duration too small, the speed will be very high, and that's why it looks like jumping.

Comment: That's not what's happening. As I described above, it jumps forward, which would be perfect, *but then it jumps back to the original starting point then recommences*. That's not a result of high speed.