# How do eliminate the "jump" in my CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, cabasicanimation

Using this code:

```
func rotateTheView(_ aView: UIView, inClockwiseDirection isClockwise: Bool) {
    let multiplier = (isClockwise ? 1 : -1)
    let key = (isClockwise ? "Spin" : "Rotate")
    var rotation: CABasicAnimation?
    rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotation!.fromValue = Int(0)
    let multiplicand = multiplier * 2
    rotation!.toValue = Int(Double(multiplicand) * .pi)
    rotation!.duration = 30 // Speed
    rotation!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    rotation!.repeatCount = HUGE  //HUGE_VALF Repeat forever.
    aView.layer.add(rotation!, forKey: key)
}
```

I get the animation I want. (Either a wheel spins, or a cell rotates fast enough in the opposite direction to always remain exactly right side up).

However, when the 30 seconds (duration) is up, there is a flicker as the view jumps back to how it looked before the animation.

I understand it is supposed to work this way.

**How do I apply the rotation to the "before" image so that when the duration expires I don't see any cells jump?**

Increasing the duration of the animation slows the wheel's spin, so that is not an appropriate solution.

If [#22521690](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521690/why-when-i-set-a-low-duration-value-for-my-cabasicanimation-does-it-jump) applies, I don't understand how - I do not have an explicit CATransaction.

Comment: Why are you declaring `rotation` as an Optional?

Comment: Yes, I need to clean it up.  I converted this from objective c a couple of years ago.  I'm only recently reviewing it.

Comment: Updated my source. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: force_unwrapping checking is an opt_in with swiftlint. I guess it's time to bite the bullet and turn it on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rotation!.toValue = Double(multiplicand) * .pi
```

instead of

```
rotation!.toValue = Int(Double(multiplicand) * .pi)
```

The issue is with the radian precision which is lost due to Int conversion.

Comment: anytime ! what Matt and  Duncan said is true. but in your case, its full rotation and initial and final state is same. So you don't have to reset values

Comment: Good catch. I should have looked at that part more carefully. I thought the Int conversion on the toValue was odd, but didn't stop to think.

Answer (score 2):

On the next line after applying the animation to the layer, set the property you're animating to its ending value.

Because an animation is "in-flight", the normal display of the layer is covered the presentation layer, a special animation layer.

Once the animation is complete, the presentation layer is hidden/removed, and the actual layer is exposed. If it is a the same state as the presentation layer at the end of the animation then there's no jump.

That code might look like this:

```
func rotateTheView(_ aView: UIView, inClockwiseDirection isClockwise: Bool) {
    let multiplier = (isClockwise ? 1 : -1)
    let key = (isClockwise ? "Spin" : "Rotate")
    var rotation: CABasicAnimation?
    rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotation!.fromValue = 0.0
    let multiplicand = multiplier * 2
    let finalAngle = Double(multiplicand) * .pi
    rotation!.toValue = finalAngle
    rotation!.duration = 30 // Speed
    rotation!.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    rotation!.repeatCount = HUGE  //HUGE_VALF Repeat forever.
    aView.layer.add(rotation!, forKey: key)

    //-------------------
    //Set the final transform on the layer to the final rotation, 
    //but without animation
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    let finalTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(finalAngle), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    aView.layer.transform = finalTransform
    CATransaction.commit()
    //-------------------
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to do: specify the ending value to the layer.

Comment: @matt, good point. I had forgotten that lovely, confusing detail.

Comment: I added the code (you need CATransaction.setDisableActions(true), disableActions is read-only)  .  I'm still getting the jump though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Duncan.

Comment: It looks like the final part is not rounding your angles to `Int`s